# Google map offline for iOS app

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

We have integrated google map in our iOS app. We have the business version of it. Is there any way we can download the map tiles for offline use without opening the the map screen in iOS app. Please let us know.

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution with Google maps sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Google map's iOS sdk doesn't contain any feature for offline. You can use other offline maps available like [Open Street Map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) .

Comment: Hi, Darshana Baldha, Does Google maps iOS sdk didn't contain any feature for offline right now? Maybe something changed? Thank you in advance!